# Delegate changes unexpectedly

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I have one delegate ExampleDelegate and I have one UITableViewController and detail UIViewController both implementing that delegate:

```
@interface ClassA : UITableViewController <ExampleDelegate>
```

and:

```
@interface ClassB : UIViewController <ExampleDelegate>
```

and delegate:

```
@protocol ExampleDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)notifyUser;

@end

@interface Example : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) id delegate;

-(id)initWithDelegate:(id<ExampleDelegate>) delegate;

@end
```

At first I'm initializing the instance of delegate from ClassA and its working fine but once I navigate to the ClassB there also I'm creating one instance for the delegate when I came back to the ClassA the delegate instance get retained from ClassB, so the function inside the ClassB gets called always instead of ClassA's function.
Can anyone point me out what I'm doing wrong and how to get this working?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? It might help if you posted the `ExampleDelegate` protocol declaration.

Comment: @MarkAdams I've updated my question with sample code of my delegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**
In both classes I have declared delegates as `strong` variable which needs to be declared as `weak` as  I came through some doc so by changing this it solved the problem.

And thanks for you all the answers which helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that you nil out your delegates once they're not needed - this will help you achieve 2 things:

1. Pass the correct class the proper delegation that it needs to handle when it is visible.
2. Prevent crashes so that when a class gets deallocated and is defined as a delegate, you might get a "message sent to deallocated instance" crash.

In your case, once ClassB goes back to ClassA, you must make sure that ClassA has that delegate defined and that ClassB's delegate property is nil.

Comment: I tried assigning nil for ClassB's delegate but after that app gets crashed like you said 'message sent to deallocated instance'

Comment: When you say "assigning nil for ClassB's delegate", I hope you don't mean that you made the delegate ITSELF nil but rather set the "delegate" PROPERTY of ClassB to nil.

Answer (score 0):

Do you intend for Class B to be the delegate of Class A so that it can call back with the `-notifyUser` method? If that's the case, you don't need the initializer and you should have the delegate property on class B declared as...

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) id <ExampleDelegate> delegate;
```

Then, if I'm following you correctly, when you create the detail controller (Class B), you will set it's `delegate` property to `self` (Class A). Now when Class B needs to communicate back up to Class A it simply needs to call `-notifyUser` on it's delegate like so...

```
// Something happened that you want to communicate back up the chain
[self.delegate notifyUser];
```

When you use this pattern, the protocol is typically declared on the class that also implements the property for it to be set on, in this case that is Class B.

Comment: No I'm not trying to communicate ClassB with ClassA, only Example needs to communicate with ClassA and ClassB via notifyUser method.